# Avro SpecificRecord File Sink using apache flink is not compiling due to error incompatible types: FileSink<?> cannot be converted to SinkFunction<?>

Tags: apache-flink

I have below avro schema `User.avsc`

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.myorg",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

The below java `User.java` class is generated from above User.avsc using [avro-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro-maven-plugin/1.8.2).

```
package com.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser;
import org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;
import org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase;

@AvroGenerated
public class User extends SpecificRecordBase implements SpecificRecord {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8699049231783654635L;
    public static final Schema SCHEMA$ = (new Parser()).parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"namespace\":\"com.myorg\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}}]}");
    private static SpecificData MODEL$ = new SpecificData();
    private static final BinaryMessageEncoder<User> ENCODER;
    private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<User> DECODER;
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public long id;
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public String name;
    private static final DatumWriter<User> WRITER$;
    private static final DatumReader<User> READER$;

    public static Schema getClassSchema() {
        return SCHEMA$;
    }

    public static BinaryMessageDecoder<User> getDecoder() {
        return DECODER;
    }

    public static BinaryMessageDecoder<User> createDecoder(SchemaStore resolver) {
        return new BinaryMessageDecoder(MODEL$, SCHEMA$, resolver);
    }

    public ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() throws IOException {
        return ENCODER.encode(this);
    }

    public static User fromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer b) throws IOException {
        return (User)DECODER.decode(b);
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Schema getSchema() {
        return SCHEMA$;
    }

    public Object get(int field$) {
        switch(field$) {
        case 0:
            return this.id;
        case 1:
            return this.name;
        default:
            throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
        }
    }

    public void put(int field$, Object value$) {
        switch(field$) {
        case 0:
            this.id = (Long)value$;
            break;
        case 1:
            this.name = (String)value$;
            break;
        default:
            throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
        }

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException {
        READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
    }

    static {
        ENCODER = new BinaryMessageEncoder(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);
        DECODER = new BinaryMessageDecoder(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);
        WRITER$ = MODEL$.createDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);
        READER$ = MODEL$.createDatumReader(SCHEMA$);
    }

}
```

I want to write an instance of User SpecificRecord into File using apache flink`s [FileSink](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-files/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/sink/FileSink.java).

Below is the program that I wrote -

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor;
import org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroWriters;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import com.myorg.User;

public class AvroFileSinkApp {

    private static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "./il/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.setParallelism(4);
        env.enableCheckpointing(5000L);

        DataStream<User> source = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(getUser()));
        FileSink<User> sink = org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink.forBulkFormat(new Path(OUTPUT_PATH), AvroWriters.forSpecificRecord(User.class)).build();

        source.addSink( sink);
        env.execute("FileSinkProgram");
    }

    public static User getUser() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setId(1L);
        return u;
    }
}
```

I wrote this program using [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/) and [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c81b831d5fe08d328251d91f4f255b1508a9feb4/flink-end-to-end-tests/flink-file-sink-test/src/main/java/FileSinkProgram.java) as reference. For some reason the line `source.addSink( sink);` is throwing below compilation error.

> incompatible types:  org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink<com.myorg.User> cannot be converted to org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction<com.myorg.User>

The project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/streaming-file-sink-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can look at the datastream interface. The input parameter of the addSink function is of type SinkFunction, and the input parameter of the sinkTo function is Sink.

FileSink is implemented based on the Sink interface, you should use the sinkTo function

```
public class DataStream<T> {
......
    public DataStreamSink<T> addSink(SinkFunction<T> sinkFunction) {

        // read the output type of the input Transform to coax out errors about MissingTypeInfo
        transformation.getOutputType();

        // configure the type if needed
        if (sinkFunction instanceof InputTypeConfigurable) {
            ((InputTypeConfigurable) sinkFunction).setInputType(getType(), getExecutionConfig());
        }

        StreamSink<T> sinkOperator = new StreamSink<>(clean(sinkFunction));

        DataStreamSink<T> sink = new DataStreamSink<>(this, sinkOperator);

        getExecutionEnvironment().addOperator(sink.getTransformation());
        return sink;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given {@link Sink} to this DataStream. Only streams with sinks added will be
     * executed once the {@link StreamExecutionEnvironment#execute()} method is called.
     *
     * @param sink The user defined sink.
     * @return The closed DataStream.
     */
    @Experimental
    public DataStreamSink<T> sinkTo(Sink<T, ?, ?, ?> sink) {
        // read the output type of the input Transform to coax out errors about MissingTypeInfo
        transformation.getOutputType();

        return new DataStreamSink<>(this, sink);
    }
......
}
```